# how to print out insert query in browser by function in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i want to make a function that have two parameters which are table name and $info(includes column name and its values)

for example

```
$info=array('em_name'=>'Ali',
         'em_salary'=>'3000',
          'em_city'=>'ISB', 
          'em_country'=>'Pakistan');
```

i want to call function.

```
insert($info,emp);
```

that give me the result as follow

```
insert into emp (emp_name,emp_salary,emp_city,emp_country) value("Ali",'3000','ISB', "Pakistan");
```

any one help me for makeing this function??

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for field name use array_keys and implode , for value use array_values and implode

```
function insert($value,$table){
            $qry = 'insert into '. $table .'('.implode(",",array_keys($value)).') values("'.implode('", "', array_values($value)).'")';
            echo $qry;
   }

$info=array('em_name'=>'Ali',
         'em_salary'=>'3000',
          'em_city'=>'ISB', 
          'em_country'=>'Pakistan');

insert($info,'emp');
```

Comment: Along with this code, please add some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$info=array(
    'em_name'=>'Ali',
    'em_salary'=>'3000',
    'em_city'=>'ISB', 
    'em_country'=>'Pakistan'
    );

function insert($info, $table_name){

    $sql = 'insert into '. $table_name .' ('.implode(',',array_keys($info)).') values("'.implode('", "', array_values($info)).'")';

}

insert($info, 'emp');
```

Comment: i try this first but it does not return any values.